# How do I create JavaScript buttons?

Tags: javascript

I have coded my main menu for the game in HTML and CSS, and need the image buttons to function with the engine, using JavaScript.

How do I create JavaScript buttons?

---

Here are some examples:

- Skip: One image button. Red, when disabled, and green. When enabled, skips the menu, when you come back to play to a continued game. When disabled, will return transitions to normal.
- Restart: When clicked, opens a box with two images and text for *"yes"* and *"no"*. If you click *"yes"*, it restarts game, and when you click *"no"*, it resumes the game.
- Sound: Will have one image button, which will be red for *"on"*, and green, when *"off"*. Turns sound on and off.

---

Here is some example code:

```
function ENGINE_get_option_state(opt:string):string {
    return…;
}

ENGINE_trigger_sound(…)
```

Answer (score 1):

You bind the images/buttons to a variable, then you can access that from your javascript.

For example:

```
<img id="startGame" src="image.png" />
```

Here's how you access the image from javascript:

```
var startGame = document.getElementById('startGame');
```

Now that you have the element in a variable you can do what you want with it. Just setup a function that executes the code you want the button to do.
The function can look something like this:

```
startGame.onclick = function() {
alert('Game started!'); // Execute code here.
}
```

Very basic, hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Paste the following to a html document, and you have something to experiment with.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#startGame {width:100px; height:50px; background:black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="startGame"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var startGame = document.getElementById('startGame');

    startGame.onclick = function() {
        alert('Game started!');
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and also this html/css menu is for an app game for both Android and ISO (iphone, ipad, and itouch). When you click play it plays the game on the phone its installed on.

Comment: Shouldn't matter since javascript is a browser technology not a phone specific language. Even though browsers render things differently this code is so basic it should work in all of them.

Comment: Well first of all I'm not getting paid by this company and yes its a project and the reason I'm asking for help is because I'm knew at this and want to learn

Comment: Do you know a website where I can read on this to learn the coding.  Also, sorry for any misunderstanding here.

Comment: http://teamtreehouse.com/ and http://www.codecademy.com/ are both free websites offering good online courses. Try them out and go with the one you like the best.

Comment: Quick question I think my problem is that I don't know where to add the codes in the coding part. As for this <pre><code><img id="startGame" src="image.png" /> would be the part where the button is going.  As for this Guessing script - var startGame = document.getElementById('startGame'); - script in header As for this startGame.onClick = function() { 
alert('Game started!'); // Execute code here. 
} dont know where this goes.

Comment: sorry about the coding part couldn't get it like yours

Comment: The img tag goes in the <body> tags, and can be styled with CSS. The other 2 rows both go in a javascript file, or within <script> <script/> tags in the main html document. You should really learn these things before even attempting to fix this game, you will only make it worse.

Comment: I edited the answer to show it in the structure of the page, hopefully it makes it easier. Was gonna make a jsFiddle for you but the website isn't loading for me.

Comment: I agree with you on that one, also I know html, css, but as for javascript need to learn it more. I just know some basic.  http://jsfiddle.net/ is back up i'll try it on there.

Comment: Try it and the image doesn't click as a button.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, the onclick event shouldn't have a big C as I did, anyway updated how it can look in a html page, copy and paste the code and play around with it. Also added window.onload which makes sure all objects in the window are loaded before executing the script. Take a few hours on teamtreehouse.com, and this will all start to make sense.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your time and help.  I was looking up school to learn this stuff, but school cost good money. If I just want the game to start without the alert do I just take out the alert part.  Meaning click start Game goes to the game with no alert.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/ is free, and they keep track of you progress, so you can leave it when you want and get back where you left of. The way they teach makes it very easy to learn.